# How to stream a PDF file as binary to the browser using .NET 2.0

Tags: .net

I'm looking for a way to stream a PDF file from my server to the browser using .NET 2.0 (in binary).

I'm trying to grab an existing PDF file from a server path and push that up as binary to the browser.

Comment: How is this different than just dropping the PDF on the server and having it served via URL?  Is this a dynamically generated PDF?

Comment: @spoon16, there is some security issues with this approach, as any one can see the pdf url from page's viewsource. Since these are static files(.pdf,.htm...etc) they will serve directly by the IIS, to whoever requesting this URL, without checking whether they are logged in or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go: [How To Write Binary Files to the Browser Using ASP.NET and Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306654)

Answer (score 3):

1. Set **Content-Type**: `Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"`
2. Set **ContentDisposition**, if you want to give a new name for the file: `Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment: filename=file.pdf");`
3. Write the content, using `Response.OutputStream` as Mr. Kopp said.

Step 2 is not strictly necessary, but it's probably a good idea if you don't want the browser to try to save the PDF with the same name as your ASPX file.

Answer (score 1):

Write the binary to the output stream, `Response.OutputStream`. Then just add the header `Content-Disposition` header.

Answer (score 0):

You can just setup a handler or a page that set's the correct response type and output the pdf to the response output buffer.