# Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?

Tags: html, pdf

What is the recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?

- iFrame?
- Object?
- Embed?

What does Adobe say itself about it?

In my case, the PDF is generated on the fly, so it can't be uploaded to a third-party solution prior to flushing it.

Comment: Try pdf2htmlEX: https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/

Comment: There's a great comparison not just of specific solutions but general strategies, [on the pdf2htmlEX repo's wiki](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/wiki/Comparison). Also, though I haven't tried it, [this](https://github.com/pdf2htmlex/pdf2htmlEX/) seems to be a maintained fork.

Comment: Try approach described in https://www.sitelint.com/blog/how-to-embed-a-pdf-in-html-without-downloading-it/

Answer (score 605, accepted):

Probably the best approach is to use the [PDF.JS](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) library. It's a pure [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5)/[JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) renderer for PDF documents without any third-party plugins.

Online demo:
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

GitHub:
https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: As noted in another answer, scribd actually uses pdf2swf to convert pdf files

Comment: I highly recommend against using scribd - I have just performed an experiment on a particular document and in firefox 4 it only displays the first 3 pages, whereas in IE9 its rendering text wrong - its offset some sections of the page. So technically speaking it is buggy. Additionally they expect you to subscribe to print or download documents! Essentially they are taking previously free documents and erecting a paywall around them.

Comment: PDF.js library actually looks like a very good solution, although the linked demo doesn't show it embedded in a page (it takes up the whole page). But it uses HMTL5 canvas, so it should be easy to embed, and it's *fast*. On the down side, it takes some js to use, unlike `<object>`: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/helloworld/hello.js

Comment: pdf.js works poorly on tablet browsers such as Chrome.  I also find it to be very, very slow for larger pdf documents.

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco any alternative with high performance?

Comment: Worth mentioning that A lot of in-browser PDF viewers do not communicate with the host system accessibility API. But pdf.js generates a semantic DOM tree which can make the document accessible to screen readers and other assistive technologies. I think the default pdf viewer in the chromium browsers also does something like this, but with various imperfections. This is an important consideration for public-sector content.

Answer (score 680):

This is quick, easy, to the point and doesn't require any third-party script:

```
<embed src="http://example.com/the.pdf" width="500" height="375" 
 type="application/pdf">
```

**UPDATE (2/3/2021)**

Adobe now offers its own PDF Embed API.
(That requires registering at Adobe and get clientID to use within js)

https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/pdf-embed.html

**UPDATE (1/2018):**

The Chrome browser on Android no longer supports PDF embeds. You can get around this by using the Google Drive PDF viewer

```
<embed src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/
viewer?embedded=true&url=http://example.com/the.pdf" width="500" height="375">
```

Comment: Better to use an <object> tag so that you can include a fall-back.

Comment: if you want to get sure it will be shown instead of auto download the pdf (as it happend to me) add `type='application/pdf'` to the embed tag

Comment: Better to use `<object>` tag because it can display alternate content in browsers that can't display pdfs.  Can even put an `<embed>` tag in an `<object>` tag if you want. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244788/embed-vs-object

Comment: @batfan, is it correct if I suppose nearly all solutions offered here address the challenges of displaying PDF document perfectly on screens other than mobiles? I have a webpage where the PDF is embedded and this works fine on the computer screens, but doesn't on the android phones that use Chrome. Please advise some tips/solution to this issue.

Comment: @PKTG I just tested this and it's working for me. See below

https://jsfiddle.net/196fv04s/

Comment: Adobe's Embed API is the best solution for mobiles. `Safari isn't the primary focus of development for PDF.js` (Source https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/14725#issuecomment-1081590315)

Comment: I wouldn't touch the Adobe API solution with a barge-pole.  Embed works very well and there is no chance of waking up to your customers complaining about Adobe adverts on their sites.

Answer (score 383):

You can also use Google PDF viewer for this purpose. As far as I know it's not an official Google feature (am I wrong on this?), but it works for me very nicely and smoothly. You need to upload your PDF somewhere before and just use its URL:

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/mypdf.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

What is important is that it doesn't need a Flash player, it uses JavaScript.

Comment: One thing that should be mentioned is that there's an upper limit to the size of the PDF that can be displayed. I think it's currently 10MB/100 pages. PS: I don't think the viewer is "unofficial"; they even have a how-to page that constructs the embed URL for you: https://docs.google.com/viewer

Comment: This option works great, but you have to make your PDFs publicly accessible, which for me is not always an option.

Comment: @riot_starter this solution no longer works, if you are fully logged out of google it loads fine, if you are fully logged in it loads fine, however if you are in between (whatever that means) it asks you for your password. And in the case of the iframe it just does not load.

Comment: You are allowed to set the privacy of any Google Docs between `public`, `sign-in required`, and `private`. It is definitely an official feature, considering any document on Google Docs has an `embed` option.

Comment: Another thing that should be mentioned is the "you have made too many requests recently" warning , which is a limitation.

Answer (score 141):

You do have some control over how the PDF appears in the browser by passing some options in the query string.  I was happy to this working, until I realized it does not work in IE8. :(

It works in Chrome 9 and Firefox 3.6, but in IE8 it shows the message "Insert your error message here, if the PDF cannot be displayed."

I haven't yet tested older versions of any of the above browsers, though. But here's the code I have anyway in case it helps anyone.  This sets the zoom to 85%, removes scrollbars, toolbars and nav panes.  I'll update my post if I do come across something that works in IE as well.

```
<object width="400" height="500" type="application/pdf" data="/my_pdf.pdf?#zoom=85&scrollbar=0&toolbar=0&navpanes=0">
    <p>Insert your error message here, if the PDF cannot be displayed.</p>
</object>
```

Comment: That's the best solution because is using the browser capabilities and not a complicated third-party solution. In all modern browsers (IE9, FF or Chrome) PDF should embed nicely. Sorry for IE 6/7 users. They have to upgrade. We've stop supporting these browsers long time ago. :(

Comment: This solution works best. I have tried other solutions from stackoverflow but I could not get to display pdf. This is the best solution.

Comment: I am trying to show pdf file form s3 presigned URL. My file types are set as pdf in S3. Unfortunately embed, ojbect, iframe all triggers download without showing the pdf.

Answer (score 74):

Using both `<object>` and `<embed>` will give you a wider breadth of browser compatibility.

```
<object data="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="750px" height="750px">
    <embed src="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf" type="application/pdf">
        <p>This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: <a href="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf">Download PDF</a>.</p>
    </embed>
</object>
```

Comment: This will not work in browsers if pdf addon in not installed or out of date

Comment: Also, this will not validate for those that are concerned with code validation.

Comment: This worked great for me, whereas using the `embed` tag by itself was deemed `unsafe` by Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: For some reason on Android (chrome) it doesn't embed the PDF and instead offers to download it. On iPhone (safari) it shows only the first page of the PDF.

Comment: @IvanRubinson Android on phones and on some tablets does not have the capability to display embedded pdfs.. also for some iOS mobile devices (iPhone, iPad).. on the other iOS devices (iPad Pro, ..) only the first page of the pdf will be shown.. this is a known issue on iOS which has been there for a very long time..

Answer (score 26):

Have a look for this code- To embed the PDF in HTML

```
<!-- Embed PDF File -->
<object src="YourFile.pdf" type="application/pdf" title="SamplePdf" width="500" height="720">
    <a href="YourFile.pdf">shree</a> 
</object>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I always end up with a blank grey screen instead of the pdf. But switching `src` for `data`, as in @Gayle's answer, does work.

Comment: I am using Chrome 44 and it won't work.  I also tried switching data to src.

Comment: type="application/pdf" fixes the problem. Works fine in chrome.

Comment: Including type="application/x-pdf" will now actually prevent rendering on both Chrome and FireFox. It should be removed.

Answer (score 22):

Convert it to PNG via ImageMagick, and display the PNG (quick and dirty).

```php
<?php
  $dir = '/absolute/path/to/my/directory/';
  $name = 'myPDF.pdf';
  exec("/bin/convert $dir$name $dir$name.png");
  print '<img src="$dir$name.png" />';
?>
```

This is a good option if you need a quick solution, want to avoid cross-browser PDF viewing problems, and if the PDF is only a page or two. Of course, you need ImageMagick installed (which in turn needs Ghostscript) on your web server, an option that might not be available in shared hosting environments. There is also a PHP  plugin (called imagick) that works [like this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php) but it has its own special requirements.

Comment: Or convert the image to PNG using an application, such as Preview on Mac.

Comment: but can you do that programmatically?

Comment: what if the document has more than 1 page? I guess you will only show the first page then

Comment: @seb it's been a while but I was able to use it on 2 or 3 page-long PDFs. Wouldn't be wise to go much larger than that, I think mobile browsers have a hard time display images like that. This is why I called it the "quick and dirty" method, but it's a good one I think so long as the PDF is no more than a few pages.

Comment: If you open the PDF using the zend library then you can do a `foreach($pdf->pages as $page)` and create an image for each page

Comment: In modern times, webp probably makes much more sense than png (much, _much_ smaller for the same content size).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I wrote this answer 12 years ago...

Comment: @DanMantyla That's why I qualified my comment with "in modern times", to make it clear that it wasn't a critique of the answer in the original context but a commentary on why someone might consider adjusting it today.

Comment: (though something that was true even twelve years ago is that there's security impact here: You wouldn't want a file named `$(rm -rf ~).pdf` -- and yes, that's a valid filename -- to be converted this way; it's much safer to use an exec form that takes a list/array of arguments rather than a string that requires shell parsing)

Answer (score 15):

You can use the relative location of the saved pdf like this:

Example1

```
<embed src="example.pdf" width="1000" height="800" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

Example2

```
<iframe src="example.pdf" style="width:1000px; height:800px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Chrome understands that embed is like Flash and it automatically blocks it. iFrame with bootstrap is a good option.

Answer (score 13):

1. Create a container to hold your PDF

   ```
   <div id="example1"></div>
   ```
2. Tell [PDFObject](https://pdfobject.com/) which PDF to embed, and where to embed it

   ```
   <script src="/js/pdfobject.js"></script>
   <script>PDFObject.embed("/pdf/sample-3pp.pdf", "#example1");</script>
   ```
3. You can optionally use CSS to specify visual styling, including dimensions, border, margins, etc.

   ```
   <style>
   .pdfobject-container { height: 500px;}
   .pdfobject { border: 1px solid #666; }
   </style>
   ```

source : https://pdfobject.com/

Comment: This was a very good solution and worked well in conjunction with bootstrap styling. It all went on top of other bootstrap elements.

Comment: Did you try with blob file? I used this with `pdf.output('bloburl')` from lib jspdf but it seems not working on IE11.

Comment: This is a good solution but it doesn't work even the latest iPhone safari browser :(

Answer (score 13):

Our problem is that for legal reasons **we are not allowed to temporarily store a PDF on the hard disk**. In addition, the entire page should not be reloaded when displaying a PDF as Preview in the Browser.

First we tried PDF.jS. It worked with Base64 in the viewer for Firefox and Chrome. However, it was unacceptably slow for our PDF. IE/Edge didn't work at all.

We therefore tried it with a Base64 string in an HTML object tag. This again didn't work for IE/Edge (maybe the same problem as with PDF.js). In Chrome/Firefox/Safari again no problem.
That's why we chose a hybrid solution. **Edge we use an IFrame and for all other browsers the object-tag.** 
The IFrame solution would of course also work for Chrome and co. The reason why we didn't use this solution for Chrome is that although the PDF is displayed correctly, *Chrome makes a new request to the server as soon as you click on "download" in the preview*. The required hidden-field *pdfHelperTransferData* (for sending our form data needed for PDF generation) is no longer set because the PDF is displayed in an IFrame. For this feature/bug see [Chrome sends two requests when downloading a PDF (and cancels one of them)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725608/chrome-sends-two-requests-when-downloading-a-pdf-and-cancels-one-of-them).

Now the problem children IE9 and IE10 remain. For these we gave up a preview solution and simply send the document by clicking the preview button as a download to the user (instead of the preview). We have tried a lot but even if we had found a solution the extra effort for this tiny part of users would not have been worth the effort. You can find our solution for the download here: [Download PDF without refresh with IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843185/7302498).

Our Javascript:

```js
var transferData = getFormAsJson()
if (isMicrosoftBrowser()) {
        // Case IE / Edge (because doesn't recoginzie Pdf-Base64 use Iframe)
        var form = document.getElementById('pdf-helper-form');
        $("#pdfHelperTransferData").val(transferData);
        form.target = "iframe-pdf-shower";
        form.action = "serverSideFunctonWhichWritesPdfinResponse";
        form.submit();
 } else {
        // Case non IE use Object tag instead of iframe
        $.ajax({
            url: "serverSideFunctonWhichRetrivesPdfAsBase64",
            type: "post",
            data: { downloadHelperTransferData: transferData },
            success: function (result) {
                $("#object-pdf-shower").attr("data", result);
            }
        })
 }
```

Our HTML:

```html
<div id="pdf-helper-hidden-container" style="display:none">
   <form id="pdf-helper-form" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="pdfHelperTransferData" id="pdfHelperTransferData" />
   </form>
</div>

<div id="pdf-wrapper" class="modal-content">
    <iframe id="iframe-pdf-shower" name="iframe-pdf-shower"></iframe>
    <object id="object-pdf-shower" type="application/pdf"></object>
</div>
```

To check the browser type for IE/Edge see here: [How can I detect Internet Explorer (IE) and Microsoft Edge using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31757969/7302498) I hope these findings will save someone else the time.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't understand, what kind of value does variable "transferData " have?

Comment: Hi @Kate, In our case, we generate the PDF based on a user's input in our web form. "transferData" contains the data which are sent as JSON to the PDF generation function in the web API. I've added a line more code for clarification.

Answer (score 12):

[FDView](http://www.code4net.com/archives/000114.html#114) combines [PDF2SWF](http://www.swftools.org/pdf2swf.html) (which itself is based on [xpdf](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/)) with an [SWF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF) viewer so you can convert and embed PDF documents on the fly on your server.

xpdf is not a perfect PDF converter. If you need better results then [Ghostview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript#Front_ends) has some ability to convert PDF documents into other formats which you may be able to more easily build a Flash viewer for.

But for simple PDF documents, FDView should work reasonably well.

Comment: Is FDView available anywhere else? code4net.com seems to have disappeared.

Comment: @Michael Not that I can easily find.  I'll leave this answer up on the off chance that someone re-hosts fdview somewhere else.

Answer (score 7):

Scribd no longer require you to host your documents on their server. If you create an account with them so you get a publisher ID. It only takes a few lines of JavaScript code to load up PDF files stored on your own server.

For more details, see *[Developer Tools](http://www.scribd.com/developers)*.

Comment: Could you post another link showing how this is done? It's not clear from the link you posted.

Comment: Seems like they have updated their website and changed this page. I think this page has the content I was referring to in my original post: http://www.scribd.com/developers/api?method_name=Javascript+API

Comment: I wish I could like this more than once, it works perfectly.  Scroll to the bottom of the website and click API to see examples.

Comment: Signups are now closed for scribd.

Answer (score 6):

This is the way I did with **AXIOS** and Vue.js:

```
        axios({
            url: `urltoPDFfile.pdf`,
            method: 'GET',
            headers: headers,
            responseType: 'blob'
        })
        .then((response) => {
            this.urlPdf = URL.createObjectURL(response.data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('ERROR   ', error)
        })
```

add urlPDF dynamically to HTML:

```
<object width='100%' height='600px' :data='urlPdf' type='application/pdf'></object>
```

Answer (score 6):

## Update - Adobe PDF Embed API

Adobe released their [Adobe PDF Embed API](https://www.adobe.io/apis/documentcloud/dcsdk/pdf-embed.html) which is completely free. Since they created the PDF format itself, their API is probably the best for this.

- It delivers the highest quality PDF rendering available.
- You can fully customize user experience and choose how to display a PDF.
- You will also have analytics on PDF usage so you can understand how users interact with PDFs, including time spent on a page and searches.

All you have to do is create an `api_key` and use it in the code snippet.

##### Displaying PDF by `file_url`

Here is the example of the code snippet that you can just add to your HTML and take advantage of their API for displaying PDF by `file_url`. You would have to add `{ location: { url: "url_of_the_pdf" } }` config.

```
<div id="adobe-dc-view"></div>

<script src="https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk/main.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", function(){
    var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({clientId: "api_key", divId: "adobe-dc-view"});
    adobeDCView.previewFile({
      content: { location: { url: "url_of_the_pdf" } },
      metaData: { fileName: "file_name_to_display" }
    }, {});
  });
</script>
```

##### Displaying PDF as buffer

Here is the example of the code snippet that you can just add to your HTML and take advantage of their API for displaying PDF if you have the buffer (local file for example). You would have to add `{ promise: <FILE_PROMISE> }` config.

```
<div id="adobe-dc-view"></div>

<script src="https://documentcloud.adobe.com/view-sdk/main.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener("adobe_dc_view_sdk.ready", function(){
    var adobeDCView = new AdobeDC.View({clientId: "api_key", divId: "adobe-dc-view"});
    adobeDCView.previewFile({
      content: { promise: <FILE_PROMISE> }
      metaData: { fileName: "file_name_to_display" }
    }, {});
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

[PdfToImageServlet](https://github.com/pla1/Misc/blob/master/src/com/pla/misc/PdfToImageServlet.java) using ImageMagick's `convert` command.

Usage example:
`<img src='/webAppDirectory/PdfToImageServlet?pdfFile=/usr/share/cups/data/default-testpage.pdf'>`

Answer (score 4):

I had to preview a PDF with React so after trying several libraries my optimal solution was to fetch the data and ebmed it.

```
const pdfBase64 = //fetched from url or generated with jspdf or other library

  <embed
    src={pdfBase64}
    width="500"
    height="375"
    type="application/pdf"
  ></embed>
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the options you should consider is **Notable PDF**
It has a free plan unless you are planning on doing real-time online collaboration on pdfs

Embed the following `iframe` to any html and enjoy the results:

```
<iframe width='1000' height='800' src='http://bit.ly/1JxrtjR' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<object width="400" height="400" data="helloworld.pdf"></object>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Construct a blob of the input PDF bytes
2. Use an **iframe** and **PDF.js** patched with [this cross browser
   workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47395608/6620171)

The URI for the iframe should look something like this:

```
/viewer.html?file=blob:19B579EA-5217-41C6-96E4-5D8DF5A5C70B
```

Now FF, Chrome, IE 11, and Edge all display the PDF in a viewer in the iframe passed via standard blob URI in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

To stream the file to the browser, see Stack Overflow question *[How to stream a PDF file as binary to the browser using .NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84995/how-to-stream-a-pdf-as-binary-to-the-browser-using-net-20)* - note that, with minor variations, this should work whether you're serving up a file from the file system or dynamically generated.

With that said, the referenced MSDN article takes a rather simplistic view of the world, so you may want to read *[Successfully Stream a PDF to browser through HTTPS](http://nilangshah.wordpress.com/2007/05/28/successfully-stream-a-pdf-to-browser-through-https/)* as well for some of the headers you may need to supply.

Using that approach, an iframe is probably the best way to go. Have one webform that streams the file, and then put the iframe on another page with its `src` attribute set to the first form.

Comment: @downvoter care to explain why you're anonymously downvoting a 10-year-old answer?

Answer (score 1):

I answered this question already somewhere else, however, I did an evaluation between multiple solutions. Also if you are planning for commercial use, these might be helpful:

**free solutions**

- iframe: Just use an iframe, however, this is not what most people search here.
- [Google Docs Preview] Google docs has a preview (See other answer here)
- [Pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) is the open source solution without external dependencies
- [Adobe](https://developer.adobe.com/document-services/apis/pdf-embed/) offers a 'free' PDF Embed API  - ***recommended approach if you are okay with a cloud based solution.***

**Commercial Providers**

- [Pdf.js Express](https://pdfjs.express/) is commercialized extension to Pdf.js (worst performing product, not expensive)
- [PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/) - Provder from Austria with rather good business support (moderate pricing, good product)
- [Foxit](https://www.foxit.com/de/pdf-reader/) - Chinese company providing a PDF web solton as well. (cheapest commercial offer)
- [PDFTron](https://www.pdftron.com/) - US-based competitor to PSDPDFkit ( more costly but also mot advanced)

Hope this helps. I might publish more detailed information in a blogpost, if this is helping people (let me know in comments).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the best way to embed a pdf for my case was by using [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/embed/) because not only does it show the pdf but it also fill available space and you can specify the ratio as you wish. Here's an example of what i made with it:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://example.com/the.pdf" type="application/pdf" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I got a problem with embeding base64 encoded with PDF because the URI limitation, so any files over 2MB won't render properly on Chrome.

My solution is:

1. [Convert uri encoded to Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168909/blob-from-dataurl):
2. Generate the temporary DOM String base on Blob.

   `const blob = dataURItoBlob(this.dataUrl);`

   `var temp_url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);`
3. Decide where you want to attach the iframe to DOM:

   `const target = document.querySelector(targetID);`

   `` target.innerHTML = `<iframe src='${temp_url}' type="application/pdf"></iframe> ``

Answer (score 0):

Go with native solution if possible, it's always the best solution as it comes natively from browser (using `embed` or `iframe`), or you can use this tiny lib to support you on that: https://pdfobject.com

Most people recommend using PDF.JS which is famous. It has been working fine until I need to work with ShadowDOM. Some pages are in blank (white color), some in black color without any reason. Impossible for me to get to know what's happening, and it's in production :).

Answer (score 0):

PDF.js is still the best for me. I use [`pdfjs-viewer-element`](https://github.com/alekswebnet/pdfjs-viewer-element) to simplify PDF.js setup:

```html
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.skypack.dev/pdfjs-viewer-element"></script>
```

Specify the PDF.js release directory with `viewer-path` and path to PDF file with `src` attributes:

```html
<pdfjs-viewer-element
  id="viewer"
  src="/file.pdf"
  viewer-path="/pdfjs-4.0.379-dist"
  style="height: 600px">
</pdfjs-viewer-element>
```

More samples for embedding PDF.js https://github.com/alekswebnet/pdfjs-viewer-element/tree/master/demo

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to host the PDFs yourself or want to customize your PDF viewer with additional security features like preventing users to download the PDF file. I recommend using CloudPDF. https://cloudpdf.io

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>CloudPDF Viewer</title>
  <style>
    body, html {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body style="height: 100%">
  <div id="viewer" style="width: 800px; height: 500px; margin: 80px auto;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cloudpdf.io/viewer.min.js?version=0.1.0-beta.11"></script>
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      const config = { 
        documentId: 'eee2079d-b0b6-4267-9812-b6b9eadb9c60',
        darkMode: true,
      };
      CloudPDF(config, document.getElementById('viewer')).then((instance) => {

      });
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,..."/>
```

Comment: Good answers include some description

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want to host PDF.JS on your own, you could try [DocDroid](https://www.docdroid.net). It is similar to the Google Drive PDF viewer but allows custom branding.

Answer (score -2):

Modern "full page screenshot" services or scripts nowadays are capable of producing long screenshots of full HTML and PDF pages and convert them into JPG or PNG files which can then be embedded as img element.

Answer (score -11):

I found this works just fine and the browser handles it in firefox. I have not checked IE...

```
<script>window.location='url'</script>
```

Comment: What is this supposed to achieve? I cannot see how it answers the question.

Comment: When I am embedding a PDF in my HTML, I find the best way is to have a link to this document. such as <a href="https://server1.network/trifold_JonesChiro.pdf" target='_blank'>Client Portal Trifold (sample)</a>  it is sometimes a clean answer to open a page and show the pdf vs tring to place it in the html. It also allows the pdf to stay open in a tab.

Comment: So your recommendation is to link, not embed? That's fine, but as an answer this is quite unclear.